# How to write dynamic about menu in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to add dynamic content inside about menu in eclipse application.
Any idea about the **About menu plugin**??

In the Branding tab inside product file i am adding static content in the About dialog. Now i need to add some dynamic content that will be decided in the run time of the application.

Is there any method to override to get the dynamic content inside the About menu???

Please can anyone help me.

Comment: Your question is vague. please add more details to your question like the relevant code, what is the expected result and what is the actual result and so on.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any research.  Please [edit] your question to include the research you have done and *precisely* where you are having difficulty.  If you can do this, I may retract my downvote.

Comment: I have edited the description please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: What do you mean by 'About Menu'? There is the About Dialog but no menu.

Comment: About menu I mean Help->About

Answer (score 0):

The about dialog `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog` does not support any dynamic context.

The main text comes from the `aboutText` property defined in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` product definition.

The images come from the installed bundle groups.

The data on the branding / feature dialog just comes from the feature and branding plugin and is also not dynamic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: I think this is not true, @greg-449.  If you refer to https://help.eclipse.org/2020-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_runtime_products.html?cp=2_1_1_30, you will see that you can specify a static or a dynamic extension point.

Comment: @ajh158 It doesn't look like you can use the dynamic product provider to do what the question asks.

Comment: Hi @greg-449.  I believe the question is "Is there any method to override to get the dynamic content inside the About menu???".  I have a similar use case - the customer wants a version number to be displayed in the About dialog, which must be parsed from a file in the install root.  I can use a dynamic product provider for this.  Do you think I am misunderstanding the original question?  Not trying to be snarky just confused.

Comment: @aj But can it be used in an RCP that already defines a static product like Eclipse itself does? On a quick test that doesn't seem to work, but I really haven't used dynamic products so I may easily be wrong.

Comment: @greg-449 You I believe you can choose to either use the static extension point (and define all of the property values in plugin.xml) or the dynamic extension point (and point the xml at a class that implements IProductProvider).  I recently switched to the latter for an RCP product I maintain.  I'm not sure if that answers your question...